# Does the pointer returned by std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::pointer_to compare equal to the pointer returned by the allocator?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, allocator

I would like to know whether the pointer returned by the static member function

```
std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::pointer_to(element_type& o);
```

should compare equal to the pointer returned by the allocator when the object was allocated. The problem is illustrated in the code below. Is the main function returning 1 or 0 in the general case?

```
int main()
{

  using AT = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>;
  using Ptr = AT::pointer;
  using PT = std::pointer_traits<Ptr>;

  Allocator alloc;

  auto p1 = AT::allocate(alloc, 1);
  AT::construct(alloc, p1, 20); 

  auto p2 = PT::pointer_to(*p1);

  if (p1 != p2)
    return 1;

  // Destruct and deallocate p1 here.
  return 0;
}
```

My point is that I do not understand how a static function can have enough information to initialize all internal state of a fancy pointer given only a reference to an object. On the other hand it would be very strange that pointers to the same object compare unequal.

I came to this problem when implementing a fancy pointer to an allocator and whose  pointer cannot be properly initialized from a static function. It needs internal allocator information (similar to a `std::deque` iterator that needs a pointer to the container internal table of pointers).

Comment: It doesn't appear that a custom allocator is even required to provide a `pointer_traits` specialization for a custom `pointer` type, nor a `pointer::pointer_to` implementation. In other words, `PT::pointer_to(*p1);` may be ill-formed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If my fancy pointer does not provide a pointer_to it should cause a compiler error if a e.g. container happens to call this function. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits/pointer_to. So, it sounds that I do have to provide this function, but indeed, the documentation mentions only that its return is only a dereferenceable pointer, which is not a strong statement. I cannot however conclude it is well or ill-formed.

Comment: I don't see any place in the standard that allows the container to rely on `pointer_to`. Making `pointer_to` work is not part of **[allocator.requirements]**. As far as I can tell, if a C++ library implementation has a container that relies on `pointer_to` being well-formed, such an implementation is non-conforming.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that's http://wg21.link/lwg2260